# What's the least number of car parked?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

> In a car park, there are 2 white car for every 3 blue cars and for
>   every 2 blue cars there are 5 silver cars. What is the least number of
>   cars in the park?

I am a bit confused about my approach to the question, according to my thinking...

---

[image]

But I still think that I am making a wrong approach. Need help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well if the cars are distinguishable then for the blue ones you need to have 15 silver ones, because you can pick 2 blue cars out of 3 in 3 ways if the order doesn't count. So over all 20. Hope this this is right.

Comment: I thought this was a simple question, but so far you have four different answers: $20$, $25$, $30$ and $36$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are $w$ white cars, $b$ blue cars and $s$ silver cars then you know $$\frac{w}{2} =\frac{b}{3},$$  $$\frac{b}{2} =\frac{s}{5}.$$

If you are not allowed fractions of a car or striped cars, then $b$ must be a multiple of $3$ and a multiple of $2$, which means $b$ is a multiple of $6$.  If $b=6$ then $w=4$ amd $s=15$  making a total of $25$ cars.

Or perhaps there are no cars at all.

Comment: agree with Henry, the LCM restriction applies to blue car relation between white and silver (which is LCM(2,3)=6.  If you have 6 Blue cars, the minimum total number of cars is 25